# To prove Z compliment is an open set without using the fact that Z is a closed set.

Tags: real-analysis

I have tried it with the fact that Z( set of integers ) is closed.
But i am not getting what to do with this question.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Z^C=\cup_{n\in \mathbb Z}(n,n+1)$ so it is the union of open sets, so it is open.